# How to manipulate a huge data set in R?

Tags: r, dataset, bigdata

First of all, I'm sorry for probably duplicating this question.
But, I've looked at a lot of other similar question and couldn't be able to solve my problem.

Well, I'm working with a huge data set, which contains 184,903,890 rows. An object with over 6.5GB.
This csv file can be reached on this link: [Ad Tracking Fraud Detection Challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/talkingdata-adtracking-fraud-detection/data)

I'm running it in a pc with the following specifications:

- i7 - 7700K - 4.2GHz
- 16GB Ram
- GeForce GTX 1080 Ti with 11.2GB DDR 5

But, even when I'm trying to set the column as Date, the system stops working.
Is it possible to deal with this size of data set using only R?

**Code details:**

```
training <- fread('train.csv')
```

Some tries which stop R or return that cannot allocate vector of size ...:

```
training$click_time <- as.Date(training$click_time)
training$click_time <- as.POSIXct(training$click_time, 'GMT')
training <- training %>% mutate(d_month = sapply(click_time, mday)
```

**Additional updates:**

- I've already used gc() to clean the memory;
- I've already selected only 2 columns to a new data set;

Comment: Does setting the class via `colClasses` in `fread` help?

Comment: Sonny it suggests to use the `fasttime package` to convert. But when I try it, I get the following message: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 705.4 Mb.` But I have other issues to manipulate. For exemple when I try use `mutate` to extract the month day, it stops running as well.

Comment: Try removing all objects and free  RAM with `gc()`. I think 16GB RAM is good enough for this. There are many kernels built on 16GB RAM. Also drop fields which you dont plan to use now. May be even try sampling to reduce the rows

Comment: I've already tried by using `gc()` and dropping unuseful fields. I just wouldn't like to sample the original data set. Regarding the 16GB RAM, I agree with you. But I still didn't get this running with no need of reducing the data rows.

Comment: Even though the size in memory might be less than 6.5G (if that's the size of your CSV file on disk), it's going to be hard with only a small multiple of the data set size available as memory. Can you put the data in a RDMBs and work with it via SQL first (with R front ends)?  See the "large memory and out of memory data" section of https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you reached out memory assigned to R. Try `memory_limit()` and if needed you can increase the default with `memory.limit(size = xxxx)`

Comment: I already tried it Flopeko! I wonder if it's better I use Python or any other languages which don't run on memory.